# SAS PROC SQL - How to convert string to date

Tags: sas

I want to create a SQL procedure on SAS with a *where* condition based on a date field. 
For example i need to count all the students born after 1 Jan 2002
The code is something like this:

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM students t
WHERE t.birth_date > '2002-01-01'
```

Looking at other stackOverflow topic I found that the solution is to use the **input()** function, but is not clear for me how to deal with different formats.

In this example the format of the birth_date field is: 01JUL2017:00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `datepart` function to extract only the date and not the time from the `birth_date` field. Also, for SAS to recognize a date, you need to add `d` to the end of the date string.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM students t
WHERE datepart(t.birth_date) > '1JAN2002'd;
quit;
```

Comment: This code return an error: 
Invalid date/time/datetime constant '2002-01-01'd.